# How to deeply infer types using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference, inference

I am currently struggling with some sort of type inference.

#### Current State

At the moment, my object looks like this:

```
const config: Config = {
  calculate({ answers }) {
    answers.questionOne // <-- SHOULD be allowed
    answers.questionUnknown // <-- Should NOT be allowed
  },
  questions: {
    questionOne: {
      title: "Test Title",
      answers: ["answer-1", "answer-2", "answer-3"],
    },
  },
}
```

For my types, I am having the `Config` type like this:

```
// The answers object looks like: { questionKey: answerKey }.
type CalculateCtx = { answers: Record<string, string> }

type Question = {
  title: string;
  answers: string[];
}

type Config = {
  calculate(ctx: CalculateCtx): void;
  questions: Record<string, Question>;
}
```

#### Goal State

My goal now, is that I want to be able to type the object in a matter of very strict. I want the calculate function, to only type the `answers` with the available question keys. So that `answers` in the calculate function would be typed as `{ questionOne: "answer-1" | "answer-2" | "answer-3" }` and not as `{ [key: string]: string }`.

I know, that this is possible (since libraries like trpc and stitches.js do this stuff), but I find it hard to find out how to properly do this.

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach using 'as const'. I added `Partial<>` just to allow 'unanswered' state (with the side effect of the types having additional `| undefined`.

```
const QuestionSettings = {
  questionOne: {
    title: "Title 1",
    answers: ["answer-1a", "answer-1b", "answer-1c"],
  },
  questionTwo: {
    title: "Title 2",
    answers: ["answer-2a", "answer-2b"],
  },
} as const;


type AvailableAnsMap = {
  [qName in keyof typeof QuestionSettings]:
  typeof QuestionSettings[qName] extends { answers: Readonly<unknown[]> } ?
  typeof QuestionSettings[qName]['answers'][number] : never
}

type Config = {
  calculate(ctx: { answers: Partial<AvailableAnsMap> }): void;
  questions: typeof QuestionSettings;
}

const config: Config = {
  calculate({ answers }: { answers: Partial<AvailableAnsMap> }) {
    answers.questionOne //"answer-1a" | "answer-1b" | "answer-1c" | undefined
    answers.questionTwo //"answer-2a" | "answer-2b" | undefined
  },
  questions: QuestionSettings
}

let studentAns1: Partial<AvailableAnsMap> = { questionOne: 'answer-1c' };
let studentAns2: Partial<AvailableAnsMap> = { questionTwo: 'answer-2a' };
let studentAns3: Partial<AvailableAnsMap> = { questionOne: 'answer-1a', questionTwo: 'answer-2a' };

config.calculate({ answers: studentAns1 })
```

---

**EDIT**

Edited to show a way to handle multiple configs without repeating the helper type for every single question settings. The helper types at the top of the second code can be shared across different settings. There is a caveat about forgetting to replace some parts, though.

```
/* definitions of helper types */
type AnswerRecordsNoBlanks<Qtype> = {
  [qName in keyof Qtype]:
  Qtype[qName] extends { answers: Readonly<unknown[]> } ?
  Qtype[qName]['answers'][number] : never
} 
type AnswerRecords<Qtype> = Partial<AnswerRecordsNoBlanks<Qtype>>

type Config<Qtype> = {
  calculate(ctx: { answers: AnswerRecords<Qtype> }): void | number;
  questions: Qtype;
}

/* set A config */
const QuestionSetA = {
  questionA1: {
    title: "Title A1",
    answers: ["A1_a", "A1_b", "A1_c"],
  },
  questionA2: {
    title: "Title A2",
    answers: ["A2_a", "A2_b"],
  },
} as const; 
type SetAType = typeof QuestionSetA;  
const config_setA: Config<SetAType> = {
  calculate({ answers }) {
    answers.questionA1 
    answers.questionA2
  },
  questions: QuestionSetA
}

/* set B config */
const QuestionSetB = {
  questionB1: {
    title: "Title B1",
    answers: ["B1_a", "B1_b", "B1_c"],
  },
  questionB2: {
    title: "Title B2",
    answers: ["B2_a", "B2_b"],
  },
} as const;
type SetBType = typeof QuestionSetB;  
const config_setB: Config<SetBType> = {
  calculate({ answers }) {
    answers.questionB1  
    answers.questionB2  
    return 100; 
  },
  questions: QuestionSetB
}

/* set C config */
//after some copy/pasting I realize it's easy to miss replacing 'B' with 'C' 
//e.g. in 'type SetCType = typeof QuestionSetC' and 'questions: QuestionSetC'
//while this is still manageable, a function-call approach like in the other answer may be more reliable? We may need to check.
const QuestionSetC = {
  questionC1: {
    title: "Title C1",
    answers: ["C1_a", "C1_b", "C1_c"],
  },
} as const;
type SetCType = typeof QuestionSetC; 
const config_setC: Config<SetCType> = {
  calculate({ answers }) { answers; },
  questions: QuestionSetC
}


/* try out calculations */
let setA_student1ans: AnswerRecords<SetAType> = { questionA1: 'A1_a' };
let setA_student2ans: AnswerRecords<SetAType> = { questionA2: 'A2_b' };
let setA_student3ans: AnswerRecords<SetAType> = { questionA1: 'A1_a', questionA2: 'A2_a' };

config_setA.calculate({ answers: setA_student1ans })
let setB_student1ans: AnswerRecords<SetBType> = { questionB1: 'B1_c' };
let setB_student2ans: AnswerRecords<SetBType> = { questionB2: 'B2_a' };
let setB_student3ans: AnswerRecords<SetBType> = { questionB1: 'B1_c', questionB2: 'B2_b' };
config_setB.calculate({ answers: setB_student1ans })
```

Comment: That's an awesome approach. But I wanted it to be a little more flexible. I want to have multiple "config" objects, and don't want to type all of those in that matter. But this is an awesome beginning!

Comment: @NickSchmidt I modified some parts to show how to partly share structure across different configs in this 'as const'-based approach. Maybe someone can think of how to restrict user answer types in the 'function-call approach' of the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

As noted in the comments, the type of `questionOne` is not quite right yet. Here is an edit to fix this:

```
function useConfig<T extends Record<string, string>>(config: Config<T>){}

type CalculateCtx<T extends Record<string, string>> = { answers: {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K]
}}

type Question<V extends string> = {
  title: string;
  answers: V[];
}

type Config<T extends Record<string, string>> = {
  calculate(ctx: CalculateCtx<T>): void;
  questions: {
    [K in keyof T]: Question<T[K]>
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=2&pln=16&pc=1#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAIKQGYEsDm8C88Cu0BTAYSjXQAoBvYeRAQwBtRcG7YCr46YB3AgJ2jwAvgEp41WrW7Q+ggHQBHXATiooAeUgF4Ael3wAPAFpj8AMoAJDQFUAMgBF4AIx2MG4PgBMaUmXOglFTUoG0gAa0hPSD0DEzNzAAtwFi94ADkNABUXNwYPb19hABpfZVVYdRgALglfWnKQyC0CWskpWkrYBlb4ACIsivgs1G6CPtKO6V4BaFqAbT7-AWMARgn+5f5jACYNpZntgGY+gF1JqRKi0rEQZFxIUEqoPEISFAxDHIIAD3ZILxCABKBAg-C8hjg-FQkHQxXgUJh6AAfMjyEgyLV3mQvsjRJRhCBYABPAAOOiIjGYrHYRFgPy+8F+-0B8BBYIhiNh8K5KOR2AkXEOczqtHmAGl4DD4OECMTwMhhqdalkJadgMJCcASeT4ABFYLPSCGABqTL+BABQl5-Jw7S6PVqvIA3L4tiKTfNTq6tTqKaRPt8LVa2aDwODIbBodyEVGkaiBe1QFSWGwOE8fliUzTiPTcaJagA3cCoLyuhqGqoi9piyXS2XyxVZZX6ytQL5q5FFDVAA)

---

Something like this can be achieved when using the `config` object in a generic function.

```
function useConfig<T extends Record<string, Question>>(config: Config<T>){}
```

We use `T` to store the contents of `questions`.

```
type Config<T extends Record<string, Question>> = {
  calculate(ctx: CalculateCtx<T>): void;
  questions: T;
}
```

`Config` will have to be generic too where `questions` is `T` and the `ctx` of `calculate` is `CalculateCtx<T>`.

For `CalculateCtx<T>`, we use the keys of `T` to construct the shape of `answers` with a new `Record`.

```
type CalculateCtx<T> = { answers: Record<keyof T, string> }
```

You will now get the desired error when passing a config object literal to the function.

```
const config = useConfig({
  calculate({ answers }) {
    answers.questionOne
    answers.questionUnknown // Error
  },
  questions: {
    questionOne: {
      title: "Test Title",
      answers: ["answer-1", "answer-2", "answer-3"],
    },
  },
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDMCWBzGBeGBXCBTAwuMigBQDeAUDHAIYA2wWdNUu5MNkA7rgE4QwAvgEoYlatU4Qe-AHQBHLLmhJwAeTC4YAem0wAPAFpDMAMoAJNQFUAMgBEYAIy306IHgBMqEqTIgKlFXArMABrMHcwHT0jE1MACxAmDxgAOTUAFScXOjdPb0EAGm9FZShVSAAuMW9qUqCwDVxq8Qlqcqg6ZpgAIgyymAykTtwe4rbJbj4IaoBtHt8%20QwBGMd7F3kMAJjWFqc2AZh6AXXGJIoLikQoKBCwwYHLwbDxCRFR9LNwAD1YwDwEACVcKBeB59NBeEgwChCjAAIqBJ5gAB8KJI8GI1TexE%20KOEZEENwoukG8Rc%20wEIEcACsQbA3CBQgI6EhQt0yDB6siANK4ACe1Q2fP5QlkFCg-IADlp8PRGMxWPgoN88RgxBxKdVgaDwez%20SAEIM4ZDoSgUUIbpKZQikRV1a0Ol1qqaYQBubwbGYwV0oWbHD1EiXS2VED5fX64f5AkEgMEQqBQmFwxFlCpoh3eYDypgsNiPb7YnOKggqvHCaoANxASA8HrqdvA3oygaAA)

Comment: The OP asked for `questionOne: "answer-1" | "answer-2" | "answer-3" ` instead of just string.

Comment: @qrsngky good point. Fixed it.

Comment: The `useConfig` function should return the argument passed, otherwise `const config` is just undefined and you can't use `config.calculate(...)` later